# Rspec prevent context switch between it blocks

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, capybara

I am attempting to put together a single run test in rspec:

```
feature "Happy Path", js:true do

  before(:all) do
    @user = create(:user)
    @object = create(:object, account: @object.account)
    sign_in @user
  end

  describe "test" do
    context "test" do
      include_examples "it_will_expand_the_menu"

      include_examples "it_will_navigate_to_the_object" do
        let(:object) {@object.name}
      end
    end
  end
```

and the shared examples defined:

```
shared_examples "it_will_expand_the_menu" do
  it "expands menu" do
    ...
    ...
  end
end

shared_examples "it_will_navigate_to_the_object" do 
  it "fills in the country" do
    click_on object
  end
end
```

The first test passes with the menu expanding, however between the two tests, the browser refreshes and navigates to a blank HTML page, before RSpec errors out with

```
Failure/Error: click_on object
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find link or button "Bicycle"
```

What is going on? Why is RSpec resetting context even though I was under the impression that include_examples maintains current context? How can I work around this?

Comment: Each test works in isolation; are you doing something in second test which is supposed to be continuous from last step(s)?

Comment: yes the second test only makes sense from the state at the end of the first step. Is there any way to make tests be continuous?

Comment: Ideally your tests should be able to run in any order. If you are concerned about redundancy you can DRY up the code you are repeating into a helper function.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this was a Capybara issue.

Capybara::Session had the following method defined:

```
def reset!
      driver.reset! if @touched
      @touched = false
      raise @server.error if Capybara.raise_server_errors and @server and @server.error
    ensure
      @server.reset_error! if @server
    end
    alias_method :cleanup!, :reset!
    alias_method :reset_session!, :reset!
```

with the spec_helper doing a `@session.reset_session!` after every test

thus, by appending the following:

```
module Capybara
  class Session
    def reset!
      return nil
    end
  end
end
```

to the top of my config file, this behaviour can be prevented.